# Is it possible to have git automate resolution of a certain kinds of merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

We have two branches X and Y that have been branched at this point:

```
test.txt
dir/a.txt
dir/b.txt
```

Now branch X introduces some changes into dir/a.txt and a commit is created. Branch Y makes a commit where dir/ gets deleted.

Then we want to merge X into Y. This will create a certain kind of "deleted-changed" conflict. Is it possible to instruct git to always "use ours" when it detects this specific conflict for the specific branch (Y) and a specific set of files (dir/*) ?

Comment: I do know that git has pluggable merge strategy modules. `git-merge-recursive` is the default. It might be possible for you to create a new one there and make it decide based on the scenario but that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section on merge strategies in the [manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html). You can specify `-s ours` or `-s theirs` to choose to use the version from one branch or another entirely. Or you can have it prefer to resolve conflicts using one or the other using the recursive merge with either ours or theirs recursive strategies. Note these are not the same things.

In the above case, if you are on Y and you merge X with `git merge -s ours X` it will produce a result with changes from branch Y.

Comment: Thanks, that's not 100% what I needed, but the information led me to the discovery of file-specific rules in .gitattributes: http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#merge_strategies